# I think my leopard gecko Luna is impacted - how can I tell?

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos

[image]

I think my leopard gecko Luna is impacted. Her belly is black and purple. I started warm baths today. She ate some large crickets and just lays around all day. Not eating or drinking or pooping. Is she impacted or is this more serious?

Comment: How is Luna now and what did you do? I found myself in the same situation

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately although stack exchange is full of knowledgeable people, we're not a very good substitute for a qualified vet.

If it is impaction, you're doing the right thing with the warm baths, although unfortunately they often don't work - keep it up just in case. Impaction can be very serious and can be deadly so I really would suggest finding a nearby reptile vet and taking Luna to be checked out as soon as you can.